# Calculate variables from 6 non-linear equations with 6 unknowns in R

Tags: r, equation

Looking to calculate a,b,c,d,e,f (6 variables) from 6 non-linear equations:

The following is my code

```
library('BB')
library('nleqslv')

y <-  rep(NA,6)
params <- function (x) {
a <- x[1]
b <- x[2]
c <- x[3]
d <- x[4]
e <- x[5]
f <- x[6]

y[1] <- 1960*b - 10000*c^2 +1
y[2] <- a + 980*d -10000*c*f
y[3] <- -2.8*b - 100*c + 980*e -10000*c*f
y[4] <- 2*b -10000*e^2
y[5] <- -2.8*d -100*e + c -10000*e*f
y[6] <- -5.6*e -200*f -10000*f^2

return(y)
}

x <-c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
params(x)

nleqslv(x, params)
```

I am not sure if what i am doing is correct. Could anyone help me out. Thank you. Intended output will be to find out what the variables a,b,c,d,e,f, are.

Comment: What means this `5.6[e]`?  And what are the expected values of `y` to solve?

Comment: I apologise, there was a typo in the code. I have edited it. all the 6 equations = 0. @LocoGris

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
library('BB')
library('nleqslv')

y <-  rep(0,6)
params <- function (x) {
  a <- x[1]
  b <- x[2]
  c <- x[3]
  d <- x[4]
  e <- x[5]
  f <- x[6]

  y[1] <- 1960*b - 10000*c^2 +1
  y[2] <- a + 980*d -10000*c*f
  y[3] <- -2.8*b - 100*c + 980*e -10000*c*f
  y[4] <- 2*b -10000*e^2
  y[5] <- -2.8*d -100*e + c -10000*e*f
  y[6] <- -5.6*e -200*f -10000*f^2

  return(y)
}

x <-c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
params(x)

results <-nleqslv(x, params)

results$x # x values
results$fvec #y values

a <- results$x[1]
b <- results$x[2]
c <- results$x[3]
d <- results$x[4]
e <- results$x[5]
f <- results$x[6]

#Check

y[1] <- 1960*b - 10000*c^2 +1
y[2] <- a + 980*d -10000*c*f
y[3] <- -2.8*b - 100*c + 980*e -10000*c*f
y[4] <- 2*b -10000*e^2
y[5] <- -2.8*d -100*e + c -10000*e*f
y[6] <- -5.6*e -200*f -10000*f^2

y
```

If we use the `x vector` AKA `c(a,b,c,d,e,f)` values and try to solve `y`, we got values pretty close to 0.
`results$x` give you the six values that make y (`results$fvec`) closer to 0. The worst one you got is `y[4]` which is `-1.020406e-03` but if you consider it close enough, you are good.

Anyhow, as @Bhas rightly says: the solver has produced an "Iteration limit exceeded", that usually means that it has tried many values without getting results close to 0 to a certain tolerance. 
Therefore, if you are not satisfied with your results (and you may not because you want requierments of your problems) maybe you want to try to iterate more. It could also happens that a close enough solution exists... or not.

For example, if you tweak a little `y[4]` to `y[4] <- 2*b +10000*e^2` you got a close enough one (this is just to show an example not that you can change your function freely):

```
y <-  rep(0,6)
params <- function (x) {
  a <- x[1]
  b <- x[2]
  c <- x[3]
  d <- x[4]
  e <- x[5]
  f <- x[6]

  y[1] <- 1960*b - 10000*c^2 +1
  y[2] <- a + 980*d -10000*c*f
  y[3] <- -2.8*b - 100*c + 980*e -10000*c*f
  y[4] <- 2*b +10000*e^2
  y[5] <- -2.8*d -100*e + c -10000*e*f
  y[6] <- -5.6*e -200*f -10000*f^2

  return(y)
}

x <-c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
params(x)

results <-nleqslv(x, params)
```

Comment: No. You should always check the output of `nleqslv` by displaying `results` or testing the item `termcd` in `results`. You will see that `nleqslv` says: `Iteration limit exceeded` and `termcd` is not zero. So `nleqslv`  hasn't been able to find a solution.

Comment: I never said it has been able to find a solution, I said: "The worst one you got is y[4] which is -1.020406e-03 but if you consider it close enough (I think it is), you are good."

Comment: Anyhow, you have a good point. I will edit the question! Thank you!

Comment: @LocoGris. If the original result is acceptable then you could always add the argument `control=list(ftol=1e-2)` to the `nleqslv` function call. Then `nleqslv` reports `Function criterion near zero`.